# How to filter records on condition if filter value is NULL in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to filter records in SQL Server on two conditions. I am writing a stored procedure for that.

This is my query

```
// Parameters 
@carNo AS INT
@carEngineNo AS INT = null    // this is optional

Select * 
From CarLog
//Some Joins
Where 
    CarLog.car_no = carNo 
    // here I want condition, I tried this but there is some syntax error
    And CASE
            When @carEngineNo IS NOT NULL THEN CarLog.engine_no= carEngineNo 
            WHEN @carEngineNo IS NULL  THEN CarLog.engine_no = CarLog.engine_no
            END
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `//Here i want condition, I trried this but there is some syntax error` What is the syntax error. Also show the query which is throwing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is simple `OR`

```
...
AND (@carEngineNo is NULL or CarLog.engine_no = @carEngineNo)
```

think of appending `option(recompile)` to your query since actual parameter set may differ.

---

your `case` fixed:

```
AND CarLog.engine_no = 
        CASE
        When @carEngineNo IS NOT NULL THEN @carEngineNo 
        WHEN @carEngineNo IS NULL THEN CarLog.engine_no
        END
```

an alternate:

```
AND CarLog.engine_no = IsNull(@carEngineNo, CarLog.engine_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

use in key word,

```
isnull(@carEngineNo,-1) in (-1, CarLog.engine_no)
```

if @carEngineNo is null then it get as -1 or otherwise we get that.